# formula for game xy to image (pixel) xy

Tags: math, coordinates

It's probably quite simple, but i can't find what i need on search engines... (it's like they used to know better what i was looking for)

I need to convert in-game coordinates to "coordinates" on an image so i can add ... say a pixel on the image to represent the location of the in-game coordinates.

The image is a map, the size is 2384x2044 (width x height).
The in-game 0,0 = the middle of the in-game map, this would also be the middle of the image.
So it's easy to find the xy to print a pixel on the middle of image:
2384 : 2 = 1192 and 2044 : 2 = 1022, so the xy for 0,0 in-game on the image is 1192,1022.

Now, for example, if i move up and slightly to the left in-game the coordinates become: -141.56,1108.11 - How can i calculate the correct xy for the image?

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYPcM.png

Comment: I think you just have to offset them and scale them. Is the image your entire playfield? How big is it in game coordinates? e.g. if say it's -10000.0 to +10000.0 game coordinates in the y axis and your image is 2044 high then you'd need to compute `1022 + (game_y * 1022 / 10000.0)`.

Comment: the image is the entire playfield yes, the in-game totals would be around -3000 to +3000 in both x and y axis. do note if i move up the Y of the in-game coordinates increase while the Y for the image would need to decrease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recap, you want to scale game coordinates of -3000 to +3000 in both axes and offset them to centre them on your image; in that case the computations you want are

```
pixel_x = 1192 + (game_x * 1192 / 3000.0)
pixel_y = 1022 - (game_y * 1022 / 3000.0)
```

Note the minus on the y line to invert the direction of the offset. Your game coordinates are floating point so I've made the 3000s floating point by adding a `.0` - you didn't say what language you were using so this may or may not be the correct syntax.

However you probably ought to avoid putting constants into this in case you ever want to change the size of the playfield or the image. It would be better to

- set up constants in your program for the playfield dimensions
- set up constants or global variables for the size of the image: you can read this from the image as you load it
- pre-compute the values 1192 / 3000.0 and 1022 / 3000.0 (but using your image constants) to save one floating point operation for each scale? probably not worth it nowadays as a speed optimisation, though, and you might sacrifice a tiny bit of floating point accuracy at the end of the mantissa, but that won't matter here.

Comment: yes, that's it! the accuracy is quite fine for my needs.tnx a lot.